# open different pages on click and right click

Tags: jquery, redirect, popup, modal-dialog, right-click

I open modal popup on click event in which I load php page, which works great but if I right click on the same button that open modal popup it open same php page in new tab which look ugly because I design it for modal popup. Now how can I prevent this, instead of open same page in new tab I want to open another page on right click. I don't want to disable right click.

So basically two page under same button, normal click->modal popup and right click->new page in normal browser window.

Is this possible?
Any solution or right direction point out will be much appreciated..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to change the way your ANCHOR tag works

Instead of href="phpsnippet.php" I would do href="fullpage.php" and make Jquery do a preventDefault() and load in the correct page by hard-coding it to a click event.

This was if a user right-clicks and opens in new then they will simply reload the current page.

Example:

```
//listen for user to click on link for modal window
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    //prevent page reload
    e.preventDefault();

    //code for modal popup window
    //this is probably not the correct Modal code so this part is up to you
    openModal('phpsnippet.php')
});
```